# jquery toggle slideUp

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

(First code)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $answers = $('.result_menu');
    $(".result_location").click(function () {
        var $ans = $(this).next(".result_menu").stop(true).slideToggle(300);
        $answers.not($ans).filter(':visible').stop(true).slideUp();
    })
```

(Second code)

```
.toggle( function() {
$(this).children("img").attr("src","./img/icon_1_expand.png");
}, function() {
$(this).children("img").attr("src","./img/icon_1_collapse.png");
});
```

I have toggle options and the first set of code works fine, and it toggles the second set of code, but I have four divs, that I need the second code to toggle “arrows” to basically on close or slideDown on other divs when it is clicked to slideUp.

```
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
```

I have four divs, and when “1” is clicked, it slides up with info, and then when another  is clicked the current one closes and new one opens. All that works fine, but I have arrows on each  that when clicked the arrow toggles to different image. All that works fine, except when one is open and another  is click the toggle image arrow doesn’t change on the  that just closed when other  was clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically this is the traditional `Accordion (or collapse)` components in some famous UI frameworks.

The promblem here is that you use the `jQuery.toggle()` function in the wrong way. `.toggle()` means "hide or show" a set of elements in jQuery. You are not able to pass two handlers to the `.toggle()` function. The official document is [here](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/).

In your case, if all you want to do is change the display images in different states, you can simply use `.toggleClass`. So when the heading is clicked, you can remove the active class for the first image and add the active class for the other one. Then you can use background image to change for different states. It may be something like this:

```
// js file
$(this).children(".img").toggleClass('active');

// css file
.img {
  background-image: url(./img/icon_1_expand.png);
}

.img.active {
  background-image: url(./img/icon_1_collapse.png);
}
```

You may see the [Codepen example](http://codepen.io/kavare/pen/xbvQmv) here.

Comment: Actually codepen example doesn't work in Safari, do you have recommendation for that?

Comment: That's because of the browser prefix issues. I just opened the -prefix-free option in the same codepen and now it should work in Safari (and other browsers too).

Do notice that if you are going to use CSS3 properties, you'll have to include prefix for those rules. You may try [autoprefixer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-autoprefixer) (for gulp) or [Compass](http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/css3/) (for sass) to lessen this tedious work.

Comment: I actually was able to just change the active to a second background image and remove the "transform: rotate(180deg); transition: all 0.2s ease-in;" all together. and all is working fine now. Thank you again for your help.

Comment: I've suffered from that, too. Just later on maybe.